# Ввод строки с клавиатуры

Tags: g++, консоль, c++, linux

**Добрый день!**

Работаю под Линухом в g++.
Делаю консольный текстовый редактор. Сам редактор у меня -

```
vector<string> Editor;
```

Потом человек вводит  строки и те добавляютсяв конец.

```
cin >> строка_пользователя
```

*Проблема в том,что строка записывается в переменную до 1ого пробела(*

Как это можно исправить? Перепробовал все типа   get(), getline()...  не помогает.

---

**ввод с клавиатуры:**

```
string usertex; 
getline(cin, usertext);
```

Comment: get\getline вполне себе работают. Покажите как Вы их используете.

Comment: getline(cin, строка_пользователя) вываливается в ошибку, хотя должно по идеет считать строку до того как пользователь нажмет ЕНТЕР.

Comment: @chudo116, если Вам действительно нужен **построчный ввод**, то советую читать C (не С++) функцией **`getline()`** (см `man 3 getline`).

Comment: string usertex;
getline(cin, usertext);

но компилятор перескакивает эту строку (последнюю)

Comment: как это компилятор "перескакивает"?

Проверил вот так:

    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
    std::getline (std::cin,name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

(gcc 4.7.2) - все работает, как и ожидалось. Может быть 

Случайно не используете using namespace std; и #incude <stdio.h> одновременно?

Comment: не дает пользователю ничего ввести, хотя отладчик туда заходит.

Comment: @chudo116 - не путайте компилятор и исполнение программы.

Comment: Случайно не используете using namespace std; и #incude <stdio.h> одновременно?
-- да, использую.  а  на что это влияет ?

Comment: во первых, смешивать С и С++ стиль ввода - это первый способ сделать себе труднопонимаемые баги. 

С другой стороны - getline это и функция, которая определена в stdio.h, и функция, которая определена в string. Да, обычно с этим нет проблем, но кто знает, что там в полном коде. Может там куча приведений типов и компилятор подставил не ту функцию. Именно по этой причине рекомендуется использовать std::.

Рекомендую начать с маленького примера, который вводит строки через getline, оттестировать все и избавиться от С стиля ввода. Либо полностью перейти на него. Но ни в коем случае не смешивать.

Comment: @chudo116, похоже рекомендованный man Вы не прочитали. 

Советую делать ввод-вывод не в С++, а в **Си** (это проще и эффективней). 

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int
    main ()
    {
      char *in = NULL;
      size_t insize;
      int   l;
    
      while (puts("Enter line"),(l = getline(&in,&insize,stdin)) > 0) {
        in[l-1] = 0; // kill '\n'
        printf ("Your line [%s] without '\\n'\n", in);
      }
      exit (puts("Bye") == EOF);
    }

Comment: @avp, это прямо как в той истории Задорнова, как он в доме отдыха попросил гречневую кашу, а ему принесли овсяную. На возмущение, почему не принесли гречневую, отвечают: "Хорошая каша".

Comment: @mikillskegg, ну тут же видно, что в данном случае овсянка легче проскочет.

А структуры данных типа vector можно и из stl взять. Одно другому не мешает.

Comment: Ну, я и говорю: Хорошая каша.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать функцию gets() из библиотеки <cstdio>

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
   char str[81];
   gets(str);
   printf(str);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Она учитывает и пробелы

Answer (score 0):

все изначально был оправильно -

**string usertex;**

**getline(cin, usertext);**

У меня gcc оказался древний - 2.0.4... Обновил и все заработало.
Спасибо всем кто откликнулся!!!

Comment: Это что же за версия Линукса?